# In MVC-4 (C# ) Is it best to use one large object that can be used many places, or several small objects that align with the views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net MVC.  I am adding to a project that has already been developed. There is currently a large user object (Fname, Lname, email_addr1, email_addr2, phone1, phone2, title, company, division...) It has around 18 fields. 
I need to create two new pages that each use different fields of the current user object. As it has already been created, do I use the original object, and just use the fields I need?

Or do I create two new user objects, that have exactly the user fields needed for that view so that I can use them as view models?

Comment: The truth is, you can do either, and not be wrong (barring some massive scale use cases).  If it were me I'd re-use the existing object, since the rest of the project already does.

Comment: Close voters: I doubt this is opinion based. There are some pretty clear best practices relating to this subject.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Two Pages` are separate in a way that each time you would navigate from `page a` to `page b`, the server has to handle a request then it would be smarter to shrink down the object in case the size of it impacts response time. Otherwise, if your `Two Pages` are not SSR (Rendered at Server Side), it would still be wiser to split the object into two smaller objects if and only if you fetch them via `Ajax` calls.

In any other cases, it will not result in any significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Its common to use 1 viewmodel for each view.

You'll maintain flexibility and independence.

Normally your view will change over time. If you tie them together, changing one will impact the other. In most circumstances this makes things harder, while making a copy of the fields initially is very easy.